# Как получить высоту рабочей области в браузере из iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть страница на которой есть iframe (url у них разный что мешает получению нужных данных)
Можно ли как то получить высоту рабочей области (Не высоту страницы)?

Грубо говоря так:

```html
<body> /// 100vh = 950px
<iframe> /// получить высоту body
</body>
```

можно использовать window.parent. Но политика безопасности не позволяет использовать это. Вы меня очень сильно выручите если подскажете как получить эту высоту.

Цель:

У основной страницы есть api к которому я могу обращаться из frame и менять высоту самого frame. Но я не могу узнать высоту 100vh этой страницы чтоб растянуть ее на всю высоту. (Сайт на котором показывается мой frame не мой поэтому с ним взаимодействовать и добавлять функции не могу)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующее

let iframeDoc = window.iframe.contentDocument // это доступ к document фрейма
iframeDoc.documentElement.clientHeight // выводит высоту фрейма

Материал для чтения

https://learn.javascript.ru/cross-window-communication

https://learn.javascript.ru/size-and-scroll-window

Comment: мне не нужна высота фрейма